# How to count the rows in the Northwind database with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I want to count my rows table in Northwind Database with PostgreSQL, but I don't know syntax how to count it.

Please help me!

This code is use for count, but the result is 1, not all data.

```
do $$
declare
produk products%rowtype;
begin
select * from products into produk;
raise notice'%', count(produk);
end; 
$$
```

Comment: Do you want to count columns or rows? Your code does neither, but it looks more like you are trying to count rows.

Comment: Ups Sorry, i want to count row

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you think that `produk` contains the whole table, but it doesn't. A variable always contains a single value, in this case an arbitrary single line from the table. Your code would have to look like this:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   c bigint;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) FROM products INTO c;
   RAISE NOTICE '%', c;
END;$$;
```

Comment: why didn't I think about it lol, Thank you very much bro you help me